# How many passwords are possible in this scenario?

Tags: passwords

A password string consists of one or more of the 26 characters A..Z and can be of any length from $1$ to $8$ characters. How many password are possible in this scenario?

- As my calculation, it should be  $2^{26}\times8!$, is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

- for one 1 char passwords, one can only put $26$ different characters
- for one 2 char passwords, one can only put  $26^2$ different characters
- for one 3 char passwords, one can only put  $26^3$ different characters
- ...
- for one 8 char passwords, one can only put $26^8$ different characters

In short, think each box can contain how many letters from the given alphabet and multiply the values in the boxes. Finally, sum them.

$$\sum_{i=1}^8 26^i = \frac{26^9-1}{26-1}-1$$

The name of the formula is [Sum of Consecutive powers of a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971761/calculating-sum-of-consecutive-powers-of-a-number);

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a^i = \dfrac{a^{n+1} -1}{a-1}$$

and $-1$ since $i=0$ is not a case here.

---

**Update** : a more general case;

Let assume that you want to build a web application and want to determine the security level of the passwords. Here a calculator;

- Assume that the alphabet has $l$ letters,
- $m$ numerals, and
- $p$ non-alphanumeric.

If we set the passwords to require at least;

- $n_m$ numerals
- $n_p$ non-alphanumeric,with
- passords's length to $$min \geq n_k+n_a \geq 6,\text{and}$$
- $max > min$, then

**What is the password space**, $\mathcal{S}$?

$$ \mathcal{S} =  m^{n_m} + p^{n_p} + \sum_{i=1}^{max - ({n_m} + {n_p})} (l+m+p)^i$$

Under these assumptions, let

- $l = 26$
- $m = 10$
- $p = 20$
- $min = 6$
- $max=20$
- $n_m=2$
- $n_p =1$, then we have;

  $$ \mathcal{S}_{6:20} =  10^2 + 20 + \sum_{i=1}^{17} (56)^i = 533361663473057950558105648760 $$

$ \mathcal{S}_{6:20}$ has 99 digits in binary form.

if max is;

- $6 \text{ then } S = 178928$
- $7 \text{ then } S = 10013424$
- $8 \text{ then } S = 10013424$
- $9 \text{ then } S = 560745200$
- $10\text{ then } S = 31401724656$ is 35-bit.

**[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) calculator;**

```
m^{n_m} + p^{n_p} + sum (l+m+p)^i, i=1 to (max - (n_m + n_p))
```

Comment: can  you please  , add some explaination ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is incorrect. As I assume this is homework. I won't supply a full answer.

$2^{26}$ suggests 26 binary choices. But that is not the case.
$8!$ would suggest an arbitrary ordering of 8 characters.

What you have is the 8 different lengths, you can sum the number of combinations for each length.

Note letters can repeat themselves; you can select letters independently.

Comment: this is not  a homework . but it was question  , i had read in past paper. i have to verify my answer is correct  or wrong and build some discussion. this is more related  to math,that is why , i  expect some help . :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739874/how-many-possible-combinations-in-8-character-password

Comment: @kelalaka thank you.i think that is better place to this question.