# What kind of a strategy can be used to crack this password?

Tags: passwords

The password is 11 chars. It has 5 letters and 6 numeric characters. There is at least 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase in it at the same time.

Can an attacker benefit from these information even though he doesn't have an info about where the numbers and letters are at?

Comment: This might help you: [How many passwords are possible in this scenario?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/62921/18298). Yes, they can benefit.

Comment: This video is not very technical but might help, you can see how hackers's softwares work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U-RbOKanYs

Comment: Yes, this information (significantly) narrows down the scope of the brute-force attack.

Comment: How could I use these information with Hashcat?

Comment: Use the hascat forums. Usege of hashcat is clearly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the location of specific symbols present always helps, as any impossible combination doesn't have to be tried. Either the algorithm to generate passwords (a counter to password function) doesn't need to generate it *or* the password can be directly skipped. These operations usually take much less CPU time than verifying that the password is correct or not by comparing it with the hash value or ciphertext.